# DataGridView - Click on Image in Cell and show new Form with full size image

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

All:
I am a newbie working with a DataGridView1 that is bound to a SQL Server DB Table via the Visual Studio Data Sources function.
I have filled the DataGrid with all the Columns in my table, including a column containing a Blobbed image, which shows correctly in the DataGridView as a slice of the image.
I would like the user to be able to click on the DataGridView1 cell that contains the Slice of the image and launch a new form with the specific image as the background of that for (or at least fill a Picturebox on the same form), but I can't seem to be able to reference the specific image in the cell that is clicked...
I have tried, unsuccessfully, using "DataGridViewImageColumn" like:

```
    imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    imageColumn.Image = this.imageDataGridViewImageColumn.Image;
    frmPic.BackgroundImage = imageColumn.Image;
```

Can someone advise the correct code to use to reference this specific image?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **dataGridView_CellClick** event handler,

So you can do something like that :

```
 private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 { 
    // set index to be the pic column, assume that pic in column 0
    int index = 0;

    // just check that the clicked cell is the right cell
    // and every thing is okay.

    if (dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(index) && e.RowIndex != -1)
    if (dataGridView.CurrentCell != null && dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value != null)
    {
        // cast to image
        Bitmap img = (Bitmap)dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value;

        // load image data in memory stream
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        img.save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        // now you can open image in any picBox by memory stream.
        // if you want to open pic in other form, you need to pass memory 
        // stream to this form, e.g., in constructor.

        // open other form
        NewForm obj = new NewForm(ms)
    }
 }
```

In **NewForm Constructor** use memory stream to load image in pic box.

```
 public NewForm(MemoryStream ms)
 {
    picBox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
 }
```

I hope it helps you, good luck !

Comment: Thanks Essam, but The following line is generating an unhandled exception:

Bitmap img = (Bitmap)dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value;

"Unable to cast object of type "System Byte[]" to type System.Drawing.Bitmap"
Can you help?

Comment: Never-mind - I figured it out - I used:
ImageConverter ic = new Image Converter();
Image img = (Image)ic.ConvertFrom(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value);

Comment: Thank you for the head start!